# difference in colored lettering on badges

Tags: discussion, questions, badges

In my collection of badges, some have white letters and some have blue. My question is. What is the difference between badges with blue lettering and the badges with white lettering?

Comment: Where are you seeing the blue text? I know if I look up badges on my phone's browser badges I clicked on appear blue kind of like hyperlink text after you click it.

Comment: yes, it's on my smartphone. I'm now on the computer and everything is the same

Comment: It's interesting what's the reasoning behind this color change only on smart phones?

Comment: Don't know. You may want to bring that up on [meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Am I allowed to ask there?

Comment: I did and mention you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That just means you've clicked on the badges for more info. If you click on another badge with white text you'll see it change.